# Is it better to have fast RAM or more RAM?

Tags: gaming, memory, windows, development

I've recently bought more RAM to expand my PC configuration. Till now I had 8 GB, I bought additional 16 GB. The new ones are faster than old ones and now I have a dillema, whether to combine old and new RAMs to have 24 GB, but throttled down to speed of old ones or to resign from the old ones and leave only 16 GB, but faster.

Older ones are reported in BIOS Setup as:

```
Memory Type      DDR4 SDRAM
Max Bandwidth    DDR4-2133 (1066MHz)
Manufacturer     GoodRam
Part Number      GR2133D464L15S/4G
Serial Number    00000000
SDRAM Size       4096 MB
SDRAM Cycle Time  0.938ns (     1 CLK)
DRAM tCL         13.500ns (    15 CLK)
DRAM tRCD        13.500ns (    15 CLK)
DRAM tRP         13.500ns (    15 CLK)
DRAM tRAS        33.000ns (    36 CLK)
DRAM tRFC       260.000ns (   278 CLK)
DRAM tRRD         3.700ns (     4 CLK)
DRAM tRRD_L       5.300ns (     6 CLK)
DRAM tFAW        21.000ns (    23 CLK)
DRAM tRC         46.500ns (    50 CLK)
DRAM tCCD_L       5.355ns (     6 CLK)
```

The new ones as:

```
Memory Type      DDR4 SDRAM
Max Bandwidth    DDR4-2666 (1333MHz)
Manufacturer     Patriot
Part Number      3200 C16 Series
Serial Number    010512d5
SDRAM Size       8192 MB
SDRAM Cycle Time  0.750ns (     1 CLK)
DRAM tCL         14.250ns (    19 CLK)
DRAM tRCD        14.250ns (    19 CLK)
DRAM tRP         15.250ns (    19 CLK)
DRAM tRAS        32.000ns (    43 CLK)
DRAM tRFC       350.000ns (   467 CLK)
DRAM tRRD         3.000ns (     4 CLK)
DRAM tRRD_L       4.900ns (     7 CLK)
DRAM tFAW        21.000ns (    28 CLK)
DRAM tRC         46.250ns (    62 CLK)
DRAM tCCD_L       5.000ns (     7 CLK)

X.M.P Support Information

Max Bandwidth    DDR4-3200 (1600MHz)
Memory Voltage   1.35V
SDRAM Cycle Time  0.625ns (     1 CLK)
DRAM tCL         10.000ns (    16 CLK)
DRAM tRCD        12.500ns (    20 CLK)
DRAM tRP         12.500ns (    20 CLK)
DRAM tRAS        25.000ns (    40 CLK)
DRAM tRFC       350.000ns (   561 CLK)
DRAM tRRD         3.740ns (     6 CLK)
DRAM tRRD_L       5.620ns (     9 CLK)
DRAM tFAW        22.000ns (    36 CLK)
DRAM tRC         40.000ns (    64 CLK)
```

The PC is used in half for various editing tasks (graphics, music, development, 3D modeling - Blender, Fusion 360) and in half for gaming (like Starcraft 2, Tomb Raider, MSFS 2020 etc.). I'm not seeking for "the best" setup, one that I have suits me quite well, I'm just curious, whether it is more beneficial in my case to have more ram or less, but faster.

Comment: No matter what RAM you have, if it's not being fully used by the system at your peak workload then the extra unused bytes are providing absolutely no value to you. If you don't actually use over 16GB of RAM ever I would suggest using the 8+8 on their own for the faster clock speeds.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/198894-raming-speed-does-boosting-ddr4-to-3200mhz-improve-overall-performance

Unless you verify that you are exceeding 16 gb of RAM, which you would kinda know as the pc would basically dog, then go with just the two 8gb patriot ddr4-3200 for 16gb total.

Keeping the existing two 4-gb ddr4-2133 will cause the new patriot ddr4-3200 to down clock to run along with it, negating what little benefit ddr4-3200 could be providing over ddr4-2133 per the article.  The only time it would make sense is if you **know** the 16gb of ddr4-3200 is not enough.

If you are doing video editing and things like that where you could easily require more ram, then it would be a simple matter of trying with 16gb of ram vs 24gb ram at ddr4-2133 clock speeds, if your task runs faster then you know.  Most times the performance difference between ddr4-2133 vs ddr4-3200 is negligible.  For a processing task that fits within 8gb of ram, you can try that task with your ddr4-2133 installed and then your ddr4-3200 installed to know first hand the performance impact of 2133 vs 3200.

Answer (score 0):

Always prefer 2 sticks of ram over 1 stick, it will be faster. Also (more important) get sticks from the same size to ensure compatibility.

based on those two rules, only the 2 8GB sticks will be best, and 16GB will be more than enough for most tasks (I had a VM, 8 chrome tabs, discord, teams and 7zip open this morning and only used half)

Comment: I actually have 4+4 (old) and 8+8 (new) :)

Comment: Yea, I saw that. But combining those is not the best idea

Comment: To be fair, there are games and software that can easily eat up as much RAM as the system has so more = better if you're using those applications. Even if the new sticks have to be run at lower clocks. If all of the sticks are being used in the "standard" 2133 Mhz mode for DDR4 there won't be stability or compatibility issues because every DDR4 stick has to be compatible with the JDEC standard modes.

Comment: I did not know that Romen, but is that also the case with sticks from different sizes?

Comment: All DDR4 sticks must be compliant with the JDEC standards or else they're not technically a DDR4 stick! All of the other speeds and modes that sticks can run at are considered to be non-standard and are often considered overclocked.